# Change font size of element with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS. My goal is to make the `font-size` of an HTML element increase as a function in JS loops. 
I have gotten `getElementById` to find the element by ID, my function loops ok  and I have a variable increasing each time it loops, but the element is still not changing.

My JavaScript

```js
let i = 0;
var myvar = setInterval(IconWeeder, 1500);
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");

function bring_er_down() {
  clearInterval(myvar);
  console.log("we stopping")
}

function IconWeeder() {
  element.style.fontSize = i;
  i == i++
    console.log("i is equal to:", i)
  console.log(element)
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Font Size</title>
</head>
<p id="myDIV">I should change size</p>
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="bring_er_down()"></input>
<script src="icons.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to inform the type of unit the `font-size` should use, for example "px": `element.style.fontSize = i + "px";`

Also `i == i++` is not doing what you think it is, it is working since `i++` will increase the `i`, but you don't need that comparision check `==`, you just need `i++;` that is the same of `i += 1;`

See working example below:

```js
let i = 0;
var myvar = setInterval(IconWeeder, 250);
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
element.style.fontSize = i + "px";

function bring_er_down() {
  clearInterval(myvar);
  console.log("we stopping")
}

function IconWeeder() {
  element.style.fontSize = i + "px";
  i++;
  console.clear()
  console.log("i is equal to:", i)
  console.log(element)
}
```

```html
<p id="myDIV">I should change size</p>
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="bring_er_down()" />
```

*Note*: `input` is a self closing tag, so, there isn't `</input>`, it doesn't exist, you close the input by `.../>`

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in the code:

- Wrong syntax of input tag
- The value of i is not incremented in correct way.

I have fixed the code, please find it below:

```js
let i = 0;
var myvar = setInterval(IconWeeder, 500);
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");

function bring_er_down() {
  clearInterval(myvar);
  console.log("we stopping")
}

function IconWeeder() {
  element.style.fontSize = i + 'px';
  i++;
}
```

```html
<p id="myDIV">I should change size</p>
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="bring_er_down()" />
```